# What happens if the House passes an identical CR to the one the Senate recently passed?

Tags: united-states, congress

On December 20, 2018, [the Senate passed a Continuing Resolution to keep the government open](https://www.cnn.com/2018/12/19/politics/government-shutdown-congress-trump-border-wall/index.html). It did not include funding for a border wall.

Rather than make it to the House floor though, there were indications the bill would not survive the entire process, and that was the last we heard of the stopgap. Since then, Mitch McConnell has said he [would not schedule a vote on a bill the President wouldn't support](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-usa-shutdown-mcconnell/senate-will-not-consider-house-democratic-bills-to-end-shutdown-republican-mcconnell-idUSKCN1OX01I). Therefore, since the president has voiced opposition to this stopgap, it's unlikely it would be passed again were another vote scheduled.

However, yesterday control of the House shifted, and (in my opinion) the new House would likely vote to pass that same CR.

What happens if they tried that?

Does a reconciliation process still take place between the two chambers' bills if there are no differences, and if so, does the Senate majority leader have the ability to block that process?

Alternatively, does a Senate vote ever "expire" (especially across new congresses)?

In other words, if the House were to pass an identical CR to the one which the Senate has already passed, what would be the next steps?